# why @jest, @babel needs to be scoped modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

we know that scoped packages are those packages that have prefix of `@`, such as `@somescope/somepackagename`. But why packages like jest need to be a scoped package like @jest as the picture below shows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbxY.png)

and it doesn't have the forwardslash `/`? and according to https://docs.npmjs.com/about-private-packages

> Private packages always have a scope, and scoped packages are private by default

then how come jest is a private package since everyone can download it?

Comment: It's up to the maintainer to decide, if they want to have a scope or not, and you can have a scope without making your package private, you cant have a private package without a scope however. Also `@jest` is not a package, `@jest/core` is a package

Comment: Usually a package get created without a scope, and then that package grow, with an array of additionnal packages getting created, which motive the maintainer to create an organisation like `@jest` and put everything under that scope, so everything is well organized, and more readable.

Comment: @Lk77 thanks for your comment, but `@jest` is a folder in node_modules, so why it is named `@jest` not `jest`?

Comment: the `@jest` folder is the folder for the scope, the packages are inside that `node_modules/@jest` folder. Open it, you will likely see another folder named core, and likely others like types. Packages are stored on a folder inside node_modules like so `node_modules/{{ packagenName }}`, scoped packages are stored on a sub-folder inside node_modules like so : `node_modules/{{ scopeName }}/{{ packageName }} `